# Return matching values in other sheet according to multiple criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

***Warning: Complex situation requires wall of text***

**What I have as data**

In sheet A, I have alphanumerical numbers In column A and sometimes, suppliers in columns B, C, D.

```
 colA      colB   colC   colD

H-19328    SupA   SupB   SupA
H-12801    SupC   SupD
H-32829    
H-23123    SupB   SupC
.......    ....   ....   ....
```

In sheet B, I have alphanumerical numbers in column A, and 1 supplier in column B. I also have a bunch of other information in the next columns.

```
 colA      colB    colC   colD

H-19328    SupA   stuffs stuffs 
H-52601    SupA   stuffs stuffs
H-3279     SupA   stuffs stuffs
H-4987123  SupB   stuffs stuffs
.......    ....   ...... ......
```

In sheet A, the alphanumerical number is unique in the list. The numbers in sheet A may or may not have a matching number in sheet B and vice versa. Even when the number matches, the suppliers may or may not match.

**What I want to do**

For each number in sheet A, I want to check if sheet B holds that number with the associated supplier.
For example, for the first number H-19328, I will check if sheet B has:

```
 colA      colB    colC   colD

H-19328    SupA   stuffs stuffs   < This could match twice as it was twice in A
H-19328    SupB   stuffs stuffs
```

I don't know if the number/supplier combo will match, and if it does, I don't know how many times it will match. I want to retrieve the values from sheet B in the other columns, C and D.

**What I have as code**

I put the values in column A of sheet A in a dictionnary. The keys are the numbers, and the Supplier information is in an array tied to each key. The dictionnary works well. The issue is not about the dictionnary, if you are not good with them you can still help me.

Right now I have a loop that matches every key + supplier to the sheet b list and returns how many times it matched. To dispel confusion, Dict_Sup is the dictionnary. Dict_sup.items(1) is an array containing suppliers. Dict_sup.items(1)(0) is the first entry of that array. Dict_sup.items(1)(supcount) is the last entry of that array.

```
For i = 0 To Dict_Sup.Count - 1
    For j = 0 To supcount 'supcount is the size of the array containing the suppliers
        nb_of_matches = TimesExtracted(Dict_Sup.Keys(i), Dict_Sup.Items(i)(j))   
    Next j
Next
```

The function TimesExtracted looks into sheet B (which is an extract, sheet name is SupDocs) and matches what I mentioned to look at the number of matches. Here it is:

```
Function TimesExtracted(Key As String, Sup As String) As Integer()
    Dim lastline As Integer
    Dim AllSupDocs As Range
    Dim SupDoc As Range

    lastline = SupDocs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set AllSupDocs = SupDocs.Range("E1:E" & lastline)

    For Each SupDoc In AllSupDocs
        If SupDoc.Value = Key And SupDoc(, 61).Value = Sup Then
              Timesextracted = TimesExtracted + 1
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

I would like to transform this function so that it would send the 'stuffs' on which it found matches, instead of sending the amount of matches. There are 3 'stuffs' values I want. I tried making it an Array function, but I was not successful in redimensioning the array to send back an appropriate amount of results;

```
Function TimesExtracted(Key As String, Sup As String) As String()
    Dim lastline As Integer
    Dim AllSupDocs As Range
    Dim SupDoc As Range
    Dim tmpArray(0) As String
    Dim j As Integer

    lastline = SupDocs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set AllSupDocs = SupDocs.Range("E1:E" & lastline)

    For Each SupDoc In AllSupDocs
        If SupDoc.Value = Key And SupDoc(, 61).Value = Sup Then
            ReDim Preserve tmpArray(UBound(tmpArray) To UBound(tmpArray) + 2) 'adds 2 places in the array
            tmpArray(j) = SupDoc(, 3).Value
            tmpArray(j + 1) = SupDoc(, 4)Value
            j = j + 2
        End If
    Next
    Timesextracted = tmpArray 'Doing this so I can redim 
End Function
```

Is there a better way to return the values I want? Am i making this way too complex? If both answers are no, then what do i need to modify in this last block for it to send an array with the following information

```
If only SupA matched in column A100:
    (C100.Value, D100.Value)

If supA matched in A100 and matched again in A110:
    (C100.Value, D100.Value, C110.Value, D110.Value)
```

Comment: Maybe too complex? I did [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31479575/vba-how-to-find-search-value-from-sheet-dmr-and-then-from-found-search-value/31480620#31480620) not sure if it meets your needs. You might have to add a second test/find.

Comment: So by using find and find next. First I would use Find to search for the Number. After that I check to see if the supplier matched - and go to findnext to see if it matches again. Every time it matches, I would like to enter the values in the following columns inside an array to return it to the calling sub. Finding the value itself is not the challenge, as I illustrated in my post. I manage to find the occurence fine. Returning corresponding information in a usable format is what I'm struggling with.

Comment: Well, was going to reply but uh pretty sure you can just go with Sid ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is pretty simple actually. I have commented the code but if you still have a problem understanding it then let me know :)

[image]

```
Const sep  As String = "|"

Sub Sample()
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet, WsRef As Worksheet
    Dim col As New Collection, itm
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim aCell As Range

    Set wsI = Sheet1    '<~~ Sheet A as per your data
    Set WsRef = Sheet2  '<~~ Sheet B as per your data
    Set wsO = Sheet3    '~~< New Sheet for Output

    With wsI
        '~~> Find last row of col A
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> What the code does is joins Col A value in Sheet A
        '~~> First with Col B and then with Col C and then with
        '~~> Col D and stores them in a unique collection
        '~~> Looping from row 1 to last row
        For i = 1 To lRow
            '~~> Looping from Col B to Col D
            For j = 2 To 4
                sString = wsI.Cells(i, 1) & sep & wsI.Cells(i, j)
                On Error Resume Next
                col.Add sString, CStr(sString)
                On Error GoTo 0
            Next j
        Next i
    End With

    j = 1 '<~~ First Row in Output Sheet

    '~~> Looping through the unique collection
    For Each itm In col
        '~~> Extraction the alphanumerical value and finding it in Sheet B
        Set aCell = WsRef.Columns(1).Find(What:=Split(itm, sep)(0), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        '~~> If Found
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            wsO.Cells(j, 1).Value = Split(itm, sep)(0)
            wsO.Cells(j, 2).Value = Split(itm, sep)(1)
            wsO.Cells(j, 3).Value = aCell.Offset(, 2)
            wsO.Cells(j, 4).Value = aCell.Offset(, 3)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**NOTE**: If you have huge rows of data then I would recommend copy the data from `SheetA` and `SheetB` into separate arrays and then do all the above in memory so that the execution is faster.

---

**Followup From comments**

Is this what you are trying?

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim tmpAr As Variant

    tmpAr = TimesExtracted("H-19328", "SupA")

    If IsArray(tmpAr) Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(tmpAr)
            Debug.Print tmpAr(i, 1) & "," & tmpAr(i, 2)
        Next i
    Else
        Debug.Print tmpAr
    End If
End Sub

Function TimesExtracted(Key As String, Sup As String) As Variant
    Dim MyAr As Variant
    Dim wsRef As Worksheet, rngWsRef As Range
    Dim bCell As Range, oRange As Range
    Dim ListRange As Range

    TimesExtracted = "Not Found"

    Set wsRef = Sheet2  '<~~ Sheet B as per your data
    Set ListRange = wsRef.Columns(1)

    n = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ListRange, Key)

    If n <> 0 Then
       ReDim MyAr(n, 2)

       n = 1

       Set oRange = ListRange.Find(what:=Key, LookIn:=xlValues, _
       lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
       MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

       If Not oRange Is Nothing Then
           Set bCell = oRange
                MyAr(n, 1) = oRange.Offset(, 2).Value
                MyAr(n, 2) = oRange.Offset(, 3).Value
                n = n + 1
           Do
               Set oRange = ListRange.Find(what:=Key, After:=oRange, LookIn:=xlValues, _
               lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
               MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

               If Not oRange Is Nothing Then
                   If oRange.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                   MyAr(n, 1) = oRange.Offset(, 2).Value
                   MyAr(n, 2) = oRange.Offset(, 3).Value
                   n = n + 1
               Else
                   Exit Do
               End If
           Loop
           TimesExtracted = MyAr
       End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: thanks Sid, but instead of writing the output to a new sheet, I would like to write it to an array and return that array to the original sub that called it. That's why I was dimensioning the function as an array in the first place. the problem is that i have trouble returning an array of undetermined size with a function. Getting the data itself is not my difficulty! Sending it back is.

I could always do your thing and then read from the sheet, but that seems slow. I have a feeling what I'm trying to do is already slow enough (The sheets are gigantic - and there are 60 'stuffs' column, not 2.

Comment: You don't need a function for this. Like I mentioned in the note at the end of my post `copy the data from SheetA and SheetB into separate arrays and then do all the above in memory so that the execution is faster.`

Comment: For the execution speed I agree that putting it into arrays is better. On a different note, the output itself (what you put in the sheet) should be returned to the nb_of_matches variable in the sub that calls the function. If not, I would need to again look values up in the output sheet you created and use the data from there, which is a detour in my opinion, since I'd rather exploit the data right away. Don't you think?

Comment: Do you want the Output (in fastest possible way) or do you just want to find matches?

Comment: The reason for me to ask you this question is that my code aims at solving what you mentioned under `What I want to do` Not under `What I have as code` :)

Comment: Ah, maybe it wasn't asked in the best manner. This is part of a much (much) larger code and is very simplified. So I may have asked the wrong thing while simplifying. I simply want an array similar to the last line in the question, returned directly to the caller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84845/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-david-gm).

Comment: Good idea but unfortunately SO chat is blocked at work, where I am. If you cannot help me further, it is alright. I am leaving work anyways and will be coming back on monday to see where this is at. Thanks

Comment: So correct me if I am wrong.. you want a function where you want to pass the ID and Sup and want an array with 4 values? two of them will be blank if only SupA matched in column A100

Comment: If they are to be returned blank I can manage myself. Sometimes more than 10 values may be returned, which is why I want to redim preserve to avoid sending a big array that's empty.

Comment: See my updated post. is that what you are trying? You may have to refresh the page to see it

Comment: yes. Thank you! A simple redim to the countif of keys that match is the part I hadn't thought of.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use already build V-lookup formula. 
Declare name range for sheet b columns A-D lets say "NameR"

Than here is your lookup formula based to pull the values in from column D SheetB

```
=vlookup(A2,NameR,4,False)
```

your first column in the range should always be lookup values, 4th column column D return value. Also sort the the first column in the range.