# Search for matching terms across two workbooks, then copy information if found

Tags: excel, vba

This code is for updating client information in my source document for a mail merge from a list that I can pull from my client server at any time.

I've hit a snag in this code near the end. The process it currently goes through is as follows:

1. user selects the merge document that needs to be updated
2. user selects the list with the updated addresses
3. code steps through the merge document, grabs the name of a company, then
4. searches through the second document for that company, copies the address information from the list, and
5. pastes it next to the company name in the merge document and
6. starts over with the next company name in the merge document

I'm currently stuck between steps four and five.'

here's a selection of the code I'm trying to adapt to search the source workbook, but I think this isn't going to work - I need to paste the found term into the macro workbook, and I have a gap in my knowledge of VBA here.

I can post my full code if necessary, but I didn't want to throw the whole thing in right away.

Thanks in advance!

```
Set sourcewkb = ActiveWorkbook

Dim rnnng As Range
Dim searchfor As String
Debug.Print celld
searchfor = celld

Set rnnng = Selection.Find(what:=searchfor)
If rnnng Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "yes"
    Else
    Debug.Print "no"

End If
```

EDIT

I tried some of what was suggested in the comment, but I'm having an issue where the selection.find is finding the variable in question whether or not it's actually there. I think somehow it's searching in both workbooks?

Full code (some parts are marked out as notes for convenience during editing the code, they generally aren't the parts I'm concerned about):

UPDATED full code:

```
Sub addressfinder()

    Dim rCell
    Dim rRng As Range
    Dim aftercomma As String
    Dim celld As String
    Dim s As String
    Dim indexOfThey As Integer
    Dim mrcell As Range
    Dim alreadyfilled As Boolean
    Dim nocompany As Boolean
    Dim sourcewkb


    Dim updaterwkb
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim cellstocopy As Range
    Dim cellstopaste As Range
    Dim x As Byte



    'select updater workbook
    updaterwkb = "L:\Admin\Corporate Books\2015\letter macro\Annual Consent Letter Macro.xlsm"

    'this is the finished updater workbook selecter.
'    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
'
'
'    Dim vrtselecteditem As Variant
'    MsgBox "select the Annual Consent Letter Macro workbook"
'
'    With fd
'        If .Show = -1 Then
'            For Each vrtselecteditem In .SelectedItems
'
'
'            updaterwkb = vrtselecteditem
'            Debug.Print updaterwkb
'            Next vrtselecteditem
'            Else
'        End If
'  End With



    'select file of addresses
    sourcewkb = "L:\Admin\Corporate Books\2015\letter macro\source workbook_sample.xlsx"

    'this is the finished source select code

'    Dim lngcount As Long
'    If MsgBox("Have you gotten this year's updated contact list exported from Time Matters or Outlook?", vbYesNo, "confirm") = vbYes Then
'        If MsgBox("Is the information in that excel workbook formatted per the instructions?", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbYes Then
'            MsgBox "Good. Select that workbook now."
'        Else
'            MsgBox "Format the workbook before trying to update the update list"
'        End If
'    Else
'        MsgBox "Have someone export you a client list with company name, client name, and client address"
'
'    End If
'
'
'    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
'        .AllowMultiSelect = False
'        .Show
'        For lngcount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
'            Debug.Print .SelectedItems(lngcount)
'            sourcewkb = .SelectedItems(lngcount)
'
'        Next lngcount
'    End With
'

Workbooks.Open (sourcewkb)

'start the code

        Set updaterwkb = ActiveWorkbook


    Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("a2:A500")

    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
        'boolean resets
        alreadyfilled = False
        nocompany = False

        'setting up the step-through
        s = rCell.Value
        indexOfThey = InStr(1, s, ",")
        aftercomma = Right(s, Len(s) - indexOfThey + 1)
        celld = Left(s, Len(s) - Len(aftercomma))
        Debug.Print rCell.Value, "celld", celld
        Debug.Print "address", rCell.Address


        'setting up already filled check
        Set mrcell = rCell.Offset(rowoffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=6)
         Debug.Print "mrcell", mrcell.Value

        If Len(rCell.Formula) = 0 Then
           Debug.Print "company cell sure looks empty"
           nocompany = True
        End If

        If Len(mrcell.Formula) > 0 Then
           Debug.Print "mrcell has content"
           alreadyfilled = True
           Else: Debug.Print "mrcell has no content"
        End If

        If alreadyfilled = False Then
                If nocompany = False Then
                        'the code for copying stuff

                        'open source document
                        'search source document for contents of celld
                        'if contents of celld are found, copy everything to the right of the cell in which
                            'they were found and paste it horizontally starting at mrcell
                        'if not, messagebox "address for 'celld' not found

'Set sourcewkb = ActiveWorkbook
'
'Dim rnnng As Range
'Dim searchfor As String
'Debug.Print celld
'searchfor = celld
'
'Set rnnng = Selection.Find(what:=searchfor)
'If Not rnnng Is Nothing Then
'    Debug.Print "yes"
'    Else
'    Debug.Print "no"
'
'End If




Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim company As String
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim rng As Variant
Dim llc As String
Dim inc As String
Dim searchfor As String


Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks("source workbook_sample.xlsx") 'change workbook name
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) 'change worksheet #
Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets(1) 'change worksheet #
llc = ",LLC"
inc = ",INC."

'lastRow = ws1.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With ws1

    For i = 1 To 500

        If Cells(i, 1).Value = searchfor Then
            company = .Cells(i, 1)

            With ws2
                'change range as necessary
                Set f = .Range("A1:D100").Find(company, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not f Is Nothing Then
                    Debug.Print searcfor
                    fRow = f.Row
                    rng = .Range("B" & fRow & ":D" & fRow)
                    ws1.Range("B" & i & ":D" & i) = rng
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next

End With











'
                    Else
                    Debug.Print "skipped cuz there ain't no company"
               End If
            Else
           Debug.Print "skipped cuz it's filled"
      End If
''
'



        Debug.Print "next"

























    Next rCell



End Sub
```

fixed code:

```
With ws1

    For i = 1 To 500

        If Cells(i, 1).Value = searchfor Then
            company = .Cells(i, 1)

            With ws2
                'change range as necessary
                Set f = .Range("A1:D100").Find(company, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not f Is Nothing Then
                    Debug.Print searcfor
                    fRow = f.Row
                    rng = .Range("B" & fRow & ":D" & fRow)
                    ws1.Range("B" & i & ":D" & i) = rng
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next

End With
```

Comment: You should be able to modify [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31479575/vba-how-to-find-search-value-from-sheet-dmr-and-then-from-found-search-value/31480620#31480620) for your needs.

Comment: I'm having trouble specifying the workbooks, especially considering the location where the information needs to be pasted depends on the term being searched... any tips there? @findwindow

Comment: Can you describe or provide screenshots of what both files are like? Where's the address in relation to company name, etc And when you say paste next to, is that to the right? below?

Comment: I can describe. The documents include, left to right, Company Name, Contact Name, Contact address line 1, Contact address line 2, etc etc, continued down the rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim company As String
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim rng As Variant
Dim llc As String
Dim inc As String
Dim searchfor As String

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook 'Annual Consent Letter Macro
Set wb2 = Workbooks("source workbook_sample.xlsx")
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets(1)
llc = ",LLC"
inc = ",INC."

With ws1

For i = 1 To 500

    If Cells(i, 1).Value = searchfor Then
        company = .Cells(i, 1)

        With ws2
            'change range as necessary
            Set f = .Range("A1:A500").Find(company, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                Debug.Print searcfor
                fRow = f.Row
                rng = .Range("B" & fRow & ":D" & fRow)
                ws1.Range("B" & i & ":D" & i) = rng
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: got that section of the code to work, I'll paste it at the bottom of the question. How do I move the data?

Comment: What do you mean by moving the data? Also, my code is supposed to replace yours XD Is there a case where a company in wb1 won't be found in wb2? Otherwise, not sure why you're doing such error test.

Comment: Yes the source document has many more companies than the one that needs the addresses added to it.

Comment: I have a set of contact information in a spreadsheet that auto-updates whenever i re-export it. I'm trying to make some code to transfer certain companies' addresses to an excel document that contains those companies only for a set of letters. -- just saw your comment I'll try it.

Comment: lol my fault. Just realized it can't be entirety of code because you have steps 1-3 XD My code does steps 3-6 so just store user's selection into their respective workbooks.