# Excel VBA code to find a certain cell and delete a section surrounding it

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a macro in Excel. Part of the code finds the cell that has "Attached Packaging" in it and then deletes the contents of a group of cells surrounding that cell.

Here is the code that currently achieves this:

```
Cells.Find("Attached Packaging").Activate
ActiveCell.Resize(2, 4).Select
Selection.Clear
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Select
Selection.Clear
```

My problem now is that I, unexpectedly, have multiple cells with "Attached Packaging" in them which now also have to be deleted.

So, to summarize: I need to modify this code so It finds all "Attached Packaging" cells in a spreadsheet and deletes the group around them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31479575/vba-how-to-find-search-value-from-sheet-dmr-and-then-from-found-search-value/31480620#31480620

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub clear()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim search As String
Dim f As Variant
Dim fRow As Long
Dim fCol As Long

search = "Attached Packaging"
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4") 'change sheet as needed

With ws.Range("A1:AA1000") 'change range as needed
    Set f = .Find(search, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        Do
            fRow = f.Row
            fCol = f.Column
            ws.Range(Cells(fRow, fCol), Cells(fRow + 1, fCol + 3)).clear
            ws.Cells(fRow + 1, fCol - 1).clear
            Set f = .FindNext(f)
        Loop While Not f Is Nothing
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Find is better than looking at each cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub clearCells()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long, currow As Long
Dim critvalue As String

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

' Change A to a row with data in it
lastrow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row - 1

'Change 2 to the first row to check
For currow = 2 To lastrow
    critvalue = "Attached Packaging"

    ' Change A to the row you are looking in
    If ws.Range("A" & currow).Value = critvalue Then

        ' Use the currow to select the row and then create an offset
        ws.Range("A" & currow).offset("B" & currow - 1).clear
        ws.Range("A" & currow).offset("B" & currow + 1).clear

    End If
Next currow

End Sub
```

Make the changes needed where I commented. It should work.

Comment: You're making the assumption that critvalue only occurs in column A which we do not know if it's true. You want to use find as I alluded to in my comment.