# Compile error: searching for one specific data point, looping through whole workbook, copy/paste data

Tags: macos, vba, excel

Excel VBA beginner coming back for more. I am creating a macro that does the following two things:

1) Searches through multiple worksheets in a single workbook for a specific piece of data (a name), variable A below
2) If that name appears, to copy a specific range of cells from the worksheet (variable X below) to the master file (variable B below)

```
Sub Pull_X_Click()

Dim A As Variant 'defines name
Dim B As Workbook 'defines destination file
Dim X As Workbook 'defines existing report file as source
Dim Destination As Range 'defines destination for data pulled from report
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

A = Workbooks("B.xlsm").Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1").Value
Set B = Workbooks("B.xlsm")
Set X = Workbooks.Open("X.xlsm")
Set Destination = Workbooks("B").Worksheets("Input").Range("B2:S2")

'check if name is entered properly
If A = "" Then
MsgBox ("Your name is not visible; please start from the Reference tab.")
Worksheets("Reference").Activate
Exit Sub
End If

X.Activate


For Each ws In X.Worksheets
  Set rng = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
  If InStr(1, rng, A) = 0 Then
Else
    X.ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$DQ$11").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=A
    Range("A7:CD7").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Destination.Activate
    Destination.PasteSpecial
End If
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

**UPDATE**: I managed to resolve the previous compile error, and it seems that the code (should?) work. However, it gets to this step:

> X.Activate

...and then nothing happens. There's no run-time errors or anything, but it doesn't seem to be searching through the file (variable X) or pulling any of the data based on the presence of variable A. Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe pastespecial? I would just set one range to another. Not sure if the ranges are same size though...

Comment: Some of the columns in the target range are hidden...which might interfere with the data I want to pull. Would it be better to select the cells individually instead of a full range?

Also, I'm not sure what "set one range to another" means... (too new at this stuff)

Comment: I think findwindow means B.Range("A1:A15") = X.Range("A1:A15")

Comment: If you don't need formatting, I'd avoid copy/paste.

Comment: The issue I have is that I don't know what row number the relevant data will be within X, so copy/paste might be my only option. Is there a way to define the row to pull the data on based on the value in Column A matching variable A?

Also, I'm now getting a different compile error ("Next without For") in this section, before the copy/paste:

`For Each ws In P09W01.Worksheets
Set rng = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
If InStr(1, rng, Advisor) = 0 Then
Next ws
Else`

Thoughts?

Comment: You don't need to activate x. And you want `find()` not `instr`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31479575/vba-how-to-find-search-value-from-sheet-dmr-and-then-from-found-search-value/31480620#31480620).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would've done is loop through the rows and evaluate the column in which the necessary data appears and then avoiding copy/paste just make the target range equal to the source range:

```
Sub SearchNCopy()

Dim A As String 'The String you are searching for
Dim b As String ' the string where you shall be searching
Dim wbs, wbt As Workbook ' Declare your workbooks
Dim wss As Worksheet
Dim i, lrow As Integer

Set wbt = Workbooks("B.xlsm") 'Set your workbooks
Set wbs = Workbooks.Open("X.xlsm")


A = wbt.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1").Value

If A = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Your name is not visible; please start from the Reference tab.")
    Worksheets("Reference").Activate
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each wss In wbs.Worksheets 'Loop through sheets

    lrow = wss.Cells(wss.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last used row in each sheet - MAKE SURE YOUR SHEETS DONT HAVE BLANKS BETWEEN ENTIRES

        For i = 1 To lrow Step 1 'Loop through the rows

            b = wss.Range("A" & i).Value 'Assign the value to the variable from column a of the row

                If Not InStr(1, b, A) = 0 Then 'Evaluate the value in the column a and if it contains the input string, do the following

                    wbt.Worksheets("Input").Range("B2:CC2") = wss.Range("A" & i & ":CD" & i) 'copies the range from one worksheet to another avoiding copy/paste (much faster)

                End If

            Next i

Next wss

End Sub
```